# Boolean Simplification (ABCD)' + ((CD)'(B+D)'

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have to simplify `(ABCD)' + ((CD)'(B+D)'` function using boolean algebra.  I simplified it using a truth table and got `A'+B' + CD`.  There is a law I am having trouble understanding

Apparently `(AB)' + (B + D)'` Simplifies to `A'+ B'`

Can anyone help me with these 2 instructions?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what our OP Tokenizer means by "these two instructions", unless the phrase refers to the two expressions $(AB)' + (B + D)'$ and $A' + B'$.  But it is certainly true that

$(AB)' + (B + D)' = A' + B', \tag{1}$

for we have, by de Morgan and the identity $1 + D = 1$,

$(AB)' + (B + D)' = A' + B' + B'D' = A' + B'(1 + D') = A' + B'(1) = A' + B'. \tag{2}$

***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Let There Be Light? haha.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ Tokenizer:  glad to.  Hey, ***Fiat Lux!!!*** is a good motto for switching theory, no?  All those series/parallel combos of toggles . . . with a bulb at the end! ;-)!

Answer (score 4):

```
(AB)' = (A'+B')   (demorgan's law)
(B+D)' = (B'D')   (demorgan's law)
B'+B'D' = B'
```

so

```
(AB)' + (B+D)' = A'+B'+B'D' = A'+B'
```

Comment: You've made it very clear for me, Thank You.